# Testing crud operations using xunit in an asp.net web api core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit.net

I am completely new to unit testing and will like to write unit test for my controller 
below using xunit and moq. I understand that you can only mock database transactions and 
make the unit test independent of the database.
How can I go about writing xunit tests for these? any documentation or sample code will be appreciated.
I know how to add the xnit test project to my solution.

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using CoreServices.Models;
    using CoreServices.Repository;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    namespace CoreServices.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class PostController : ControllerBase
        {
            IPostRepository postRepository;
            public PostController(IPostRepository _postRepository)
            {
                postRepository = _postRepository;
            }

            [HttpGet]
            [Route("GetCategories")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategories()
            {
                try
                {
                    var categories = await postRepository.GetCategories();
                    if (categories == null)
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }

                    return Ok(categories);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

            }

            [HttpGet]
            [Route("GetPosts")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetPosts()
            {
                try
                {
                    var posts = await postRepository.GetPosts();
                    if (posts == null)
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }

                    return Ok(posts);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }

            [HttpGet]
            [Route("GetPost")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetPost(int? postId)
            {
                if (postId == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                try
                {
                    var post = await postRepository.GetPost(postId);

                    if (post == null)
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }

                    return Ok(post);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }

            [HttpPost]
            [Route("AddPost")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> AddPost([FromBody]Post model)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var postId = await postRepository.AddPost(model);
                        if (postId > 0)
                        {
                            return Ok(postId);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return NotFound();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        return BadRequest();
                    }

                }

                return BadRequest();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            [Route("DeletePost")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePost(int? postId)
            {
                int result = 0;

                if (postId == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                try
                {
                    result = await postRepository.DeletePost(postId);
                    if (result == 0)
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    return Ok();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }


            [HttpPost]
            [Route("UpdatePost")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> UpdatePost([FromBody]Post model)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await postRepository.UpdatePost(model);

                        return Ok();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (ex.GetType().FullName == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException")
                        {
                            return NotFound();
                        }

                        return BadRequest();
                    }
                }

                return BadRequest();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Mock the dependency, inject into the subject under test and verify the expected behavior when the test is exercised.

Comment: I know mock is the solution. How? Any sample code?

Answer (score 3):

You can just instantiate that controller with new PostController(postRepository).
If you need a mock for the post repository you can use a library called Moq. (Use nuget to get it). Simply write:

```
using Moq;

Mock<IPostRepository> postRepositoryMock = new Mock<IPostRepository>();
PostController controller = new PostController(postRepositoryMock.Object);
```

then you can use the Setup method on the Mock to return what you want. For example to Mock the Get method in a way that returns a test Post for any given Id of type int?:

```
postRepositoryMock.Setup(it => it.Get(It.IsAny<int?>()).Returns(new Post() { //here what you need to build your post object })
```

Then you can execute the code to get the result from the controller, for example (Test Code is made using NUnit, I don't use xunit but the concept is the same):

```
using Moq;

[TestFixture]
public class ExampleFixture()
{
    [Test]
    public void ExampleTest()
    { 

        Mock<IPostRepository> postRepositoryMock = new Mock<IPostRepository>();

        PostController controller = new PostController(postRepositoryMock.Object);

        postRepositoryMock.Setup(it => it.Get(It.IsAny<int?>()).Returns(new Post() { //here what you need to build your post object })

        var result = controller.GetPost(1);

        Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null, "Unexpected null result");

        var retrievedPostContent = result as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Post>;
        Assert.That(retrievedPostContent, Is.Not.Null, "Unexpected null retrievedPost");
        var retrievedPost = result.Content;
        Assert.That(retrievedPost.Id, Is.EqualTo(1), "retrievedPost.Id is unexpected")
    }
}
```

with xUnit should became:

```
using Xunit;
using Moq;

namespace ATestNamespace
{
public class TestFixture
{

    public TestFixture()
    {

    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {

        Mock<IPostRepository> postRepositoryMock = new Mock<IPostRepository>();

        PostController controller = new PostController(postRepositoryMock.Object);

        postRepositoryMock.Setup(it => it.Get(It.IsAny<int?>()).Returns(new Post() { //here what you need to build your post object });

        var result = controller.GetPost(1);
        Assert.True(result != null,"Unexpected null result");

        var retrievedPostResult = result as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Post>;
        Assert.True(retrievedPostResult != null, "Unexpected null retrievedPost");

        var retrievedPost = result.Content;
        Assert.True(retrievedPost.Id == 1, "retrievedPost.Id is unexpected")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend to combine it with https://github.com/ivaylokenov/MyTested.WebApi/tree/master in order to be able to test routing, filtering and route parameters mapping.